# Protecting against malicious users passing arrays as POST parameters into a PHP application

Tags: php, security, post

A user reported that changing our post request *(directly using live http headers)* from `notes` to `notes[]` broke our **php** application and also exposed our full path (error reporting on).

Short of going through our entire application and doing:

```
 if(is_array($_POST['some_param'])) {
    die("Invalid parameter");
 }
```

Is there a better way to protect against this type of attack?

Comment: +1 *prima facia* for unexplained (& IMO unjustified) down vote.

Answer (score 2):

Testing for invalid values makes for a nasty game of cat and mouse. Try the opposite pattern where you proceed only on expected types.

In your scenario, test to see if `$_POST['some_param']` represents a single text value and only then proceed with processing the request.

Answer (score 1):

Checking the expected type being passed around is the best way to go about it.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Turning off error reporting in a production environment is always helpful.  You can always check your error logs through what ever server you're using (Apache, nginx, etc).

As far as checking all post variables for if they are an array, if you're worried about it, you can always use your included header in all files to just iterate over your _POST variable and clean it up, this is called sanitizing your variables, there are many articles on the internet on how to go about this, here is an article that could help you understand this:

http://www.dreamhost.com/dreamscape/2013/05/22/php-security-user-validation-and-sanitization-for-the-beginner/

Comment: If you turn of error reporting they aren’t logged either. I think you meant [*display_errors*](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors), which should always be disabled in production since the user is not meant to see technical error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you use `notes` in many different places, you don't have a single gateway (eg all routes through `index.php`), and you want to add some protection.

If so, I suggest using the [`auto_prepend_file`](http://jesin.tk/php-auto_prepend_file-and-auto_append_file/) configuration value to load in a script (call it say `input-filters.php`) that does something like:

```
$_POST = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, [ 'notes' => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR ]);
```

There's tons more you can do with filters, so [do check out the examples](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php).

Comment: Correct, we **don't** want arrays passed as `$_POST` parameters.

Comment: @halfer @Justin Thanks, fixed that to `REQUIRE_SCALAR`